# Is there analog of Javolution ArrayFactory

Tags: java, arrays, pool

My android app need a lot of arrays. To prevent GC, I started to use [Javolution.arrayFactory](http://javolution.org/target/site/apidocs/javolution/context/ArrayFactory.html).
 But if I `alloc` memory in one thread calling like following.

```
byte []buffer = ArrayFactory.BYTES_FACTORY.array(size);
```

And free it in another thread like following.

```
ArrayFactory.BYTES_FACTORY.recycle(buffer);
```

Then It couse memory leak. I need library or just class which realize array's pool.

Comment: Why does that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Eclipse Memory Analizator says than  fastmap holds it after recycling.

Comment: That is what object pooling generally does, yes. Perhaps they forgot to use a `WeakReference`?

Comment: Does arrayFactory needs WeakReference?

Comment: If you don't want to prevent the references from being garbage collected, yes, but that's generally something you want when pooling objects.

Comment: I don't want to rewrite Javolution Library.

Comment: My point is merely that it's not a memory leak and that it's an intentional side-effect of pooling hard references to your data.

Comment: I don't holds any references to this array. And Memory Analizator says, that it is FastMap.

Comment: I never accused you of directly holding a hard reference... it is the Javolution array pool that does.

Comment: My english is not so good and maybe I undersood you wrong.
Do you know an analog of array factory?

Comment: Do not worry, friend; I did not mean to offend you. The "leak" is because the allocator purposefully does not release the objects. Are you using `HeapContext` or `ImmortalContext`?

Comment: No, I just use only to lines of code. You could see it in my question.

Comment: Okay, it appears the default allocator is `HeapContext.HeapAllocator`. Now, is the leak from `FastMap` or from `FastTable`?

Comment: Memory Analizator says, that it is FastMap

Comment: I suspect the leak is in [HeapContext](http://kenai.com/projects/javolution/sources/source-code-repository/content/Javolution/src/main/java/_templates/javolution/context/HeapContext.java), involving the `FastMap` underlying `FACTORY_TO_ALLOCATOR`. Each `HeapAllocator` then maintains a `FastTable` of every object released through it, which includes the arrays released via `ArrayFactory.release`.

Comment: I just add `PoolContext.enter();` and `PoolContext.exit();` for my threads and now my app can work more than 10 minutes. 10tx.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of allocating lots of byte[] there are usually ways of reusing them rather than dynamically recycling them.

e.g. say you have a Socket handler object and it has a byte[]. You can create byte[] once and keep this for the life of the connection.

You can have a ByteBuffer which is split in multiple places to create multiple buffers using the same byte array.

Or you can store the data using structures you design such as off heap memory (I suspect this works better for the JVM than it does for Android)

I used to recycle a lot of `byte[]` but in time found ways on different projects to replace all of them with pre-allocated or long lived buffers and this had much lower CPU overhead.